# SELECT clause with three tables together

Tags: sql, oracle

Example, having these 3 tables

DEPARTMENT

```
//DEPARTMENT
DNAME       BUDGET      CHAIRMAN
----------------------------------
RESEARCH     2000         JOHN
   IT        3000          MAY
 SCIENCE     5000         KING
```

PROJECT

```
//PROJECT
P#     TITLE     BUDGET    STARTD          ENDD
----------------------------------------------------
1      COMPUTING   200     13-10-1993      13-11-1993
2       CODING     300     15-10-1993      15-12-1993
3      SEARCHING   188     07-07-1995      08-08-1995
```

DP <--Assume constraint references done already, just didn't show the coding here

```
//DP
DNAME        P#
----------------
RESEARCH      1
  IT          2
RESEARCH      3
```

SO when i run this statement

```
SELECT d.DNAME,d.BUDGET,d.CHAIRMAN,p.TITLE,p.BUDGET,p.STARTD,p.ENDD 
     FROM DEPARTMENT d INNER JOIN PROJECT p 
     INNER JOIN DP dp ON DP.P#=p.P#;
```

but show some errors. want to get output like this:
Only display those involved in the project tables

```
DNAME    BUDGET   CHAIRMAN     TITLE      BUDGET     STARTD        ENDD
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESEARCH  2000     JOHN       COMPUTING    200       13-10-1993  13-11-1993
RESEARCH  2000     JOHN       SEARCHING    188       07-07-1995  08-08-1995
   IT     3000      MAY         CODING     300       15-10-1993  15-12-1993
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the query to:

```
SELECT d.DNAME,d.BUDGET,d.CHAIRMAN,p.TITLE,p.BUDGET,p.STARTD,p.ENDD 
     FROM DEPARTMENT d INNER JOIN dp on dp.dname=d.dname
     INNER JOIN project p ON DP.P=p.P;
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6f5ee/1)

Comment: worked perfectly. but made some changes as your table name not correct with mine, product = project. =)